# Why is execPopulate method required in mongoose for populating an existing document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I know the syntax of it and how it works, but I cannot understand the internal workings, why does a method chaining require another method at one time, but doesn't some other time?

This code works fine

```
const cart = await Carts.findById(cartId).populate('product');
```

But this code does not

```
let cart = await Carts.findById(cartId);
cart = await cart.populate('product');
```

And to make it work, we use the `execPopulate` method which works like this.

```
let cart = await Carts.findById(cartId);
cart = await cart.populate('product').execPopulate();
```

Now, as far as I have read method chaining in javascript, the code should run fine without the `execPopulate` method too. But I cannot seem to understand why populate does not work on existing mongoose objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Carts.findById(cartId);` returns query Object.

When you use `await Carts.findById(cartId);` it returns the document as it will resolve the promise and fetch the result.

> The await operator is used to wait for a Promise.

---

```
let cart = await Carts.findById(cartId); // cart document fetched by query
cart = await cart.populate('product'); // you can't run populate method on document
```

---

Valid case

```
const cartQuery = Carts.findById(cartId);
const cart = await cartQuery.populate('product');
```

---

[.execPopulate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-execPopulate) is method on document, while [.populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-populate) works on query object.

Answer (score 18):

Just a note for anyone reading this that `execPopulate()` has now been removed: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#removed-execpopulate

Comment: And they said superheroes don't exist.

Comment: Please let us know if there is any replacement for execPopulate

Comment: @anurag1905 please see the link to the docs I posted above, it shows a replacement.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `populate()` method on two different types of objects - ie a `query` and a `document` - which have their own specification for the method.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-populate
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-populate

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering the same thing the other day.