# Getting errors while using .populate() function in moongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using .populate function of moongoose and i have 3 collections named admins user and courses . my user object contain purchased courses array which has reference id of courses and i want to retrieve the courses using .populate function

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose= require('mongoose');
app.use(express.json());
const jwt=require('jsonwebtoken');

const userscheme = new mongoose.Schema({
  username:String,
  password:String,
  purchasedCourses:[{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Course'}]
});
const adminSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
  username:String,
  password:String
});
const courseschema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title:String,
  description:String,
  price:Number,
  published:Boolean,
});
const User = mongoose.model('User',userscheme);
const Admins=mongoose.model('Admins',adminSchema);
const Course=mongoose.model('Course',courseschema);
// Admin routes
const usersecretkey = "secr3tkeyuser";
const adminsecretkey ="secr3tkeyadmin";
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://Courses-site:bbqzz1VJRZXANR6z@cluster0.dbonjha.mongodb.net/', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, dbName: "courses-harkirat" });
const generateadmin =(admin)=>{
  const token = jwt.sign({admin,
  },adminsecretkey);
  return token;
}
const authenticateuser=async(req,res,next)=>{
  const tokenHeader = req.headers.authorization;
 console.log("hiee");
  console.log(tokenHeader);
  if (tokenHeader) {
      const token = tokenHeader.split(' ')[1];
      console.log(token);
      try {
          const val = jwt.verify(token, usersecretkey);
          console.log(val);

          const admin = await User.findOne({username:val.username});
         // console.log(admin);
          console.log(admin);
          if (admin) {
            req.admin=admin;
              next();
          } else {
              res.status(401).json( "Unauthorized - User not found" );
          }
      } catch (error) {
       // console.error("catch block error",error);
          console.error("Token verification error:", error);
          res.status(401).json( "Unauthorized - Invalid token" );
      }
  } else {
      res.status(401).json("Unauthorized - Token not provided" );
  }
}
app.get('/users/purchasedCourses', authenticateuser,async(req, res) => {
  try {
    // Populate the 'purchasedCourses' field of the 'admin' document
    await req.admin.populate('purchasedCourses').execPopulate();

    // Retrieve the populated purchased courses from the admin document
    const purchasedCourses = req.admin.purchasedCourses;

    // Send back the populated purchased courses
    res.json(purchasedCourses);
} catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error" });
}
});
```

and this is my admin which i am consolingto verying it is an object or not

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("65f5d91cd9e616593d591c7b"),
  username: 'holi aa rhi h',
  password: 'vrindavan chle jldi',
  purchasedCourses: [
    new ObjectId("65f4299e6277b849cb84c680"),
    new ObjectId("65f41eaaa734861045b85aa8")
  ],
  __v: 2
}
```

and this is the error which i am getting
Error: TypeError: req.admin.populate(...).execPopulate is not a function
at C:\Users\Dell\OneDrive\Desktop\all-assignments\week-3\04-course-app-hard\index.js:227:50
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Dell\OneDrive\Desktop\all-assignments\week-3\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\Users\Dell\OneDrive\Desktop\all-assignments\week-3\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
at authenticateuser (C:\Users\Dell\OneDrive\Desktop\all-assignments\week-3\04-course-app-hard\index.js:70:15)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Comment: You are populating admin with purchasedCourses, but admin schema doesn't have that field. The field exists in user schema

Comment: but here admin didnt refer to the admin scheme it is refering to the admin variable i make in authenticateuser middleware

Comment: I guess your issue is because of this. do check
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67159047